# Firefox shows symbols instead of letters

Tags: firefox, fonts, locale

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and now Firefox shows symbols instead of letters. I tried to update locales and clear system font cache, none of that helped. Did a clean Firefox install and it's still not showing letters correctly. I have 2 languages in my system en_US and ru_RU

[image]

Comment: Check system settings > Region & Language. Very likely you have an incomplete installation of one or the other.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Preferences --> Language & Appearance --> Fonts & Colors --> Advanced? Also add Firefox version and locale of installation.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to fix everything! Go to Settings-Appearance-Fonts and select a proper font that supports english symbols! I had empty field here that's why I had symbols instead of letters not only in Firefox but in every other program.
[image]